# If I'm a ruler of a Jewish kingdom outside Israel can I make my own laws/state-philosophies like Confucianism as long as they don't contradict Halacha

Tags: halacha

Let's say that I'm hypothetically a ruler of a kingdom and my kingdom becomes Jewish along with me and the elites, etc. and some good chunk of the populace.

Am I then allowed to make my own laws (like completely my own laws, based on what I think is right) and/or implement ideologies/philosophies similar to say Confucianism at state-level as long as they don't interfere with the Halacha or would I have to see what the Halacha says and come up with the relevant law based on that? And would Talmudic laws and Halacha in general become also the base law of the country?

Comment: What would be the reason this might be prohibited?

Comment: Rav Soloveitchik had a line that owning his house in Boston doesn't constitute a "Kibbush Yachid" (personal conquest) that would make it a part of Eretz Yisrael and obligated in the land related Mitzvot. (Nefesh HaRav pg 83)

I imagine doing anything you like outside of Eretz Yisrael is fair game as long as you follow the halacha.